# Why my render material doesnt looks like as my preview

Tags: texturing

I have a glossy material but as soon I render it, it turns plain and no reflexions...probably is super simple solution but I cant figure it out[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file, because the information you gave us isn't enough. And assuming you are a beginner we would have to ask for several settings and screenshots...so it is much quicker to provide your blend file.

Comment: maybe there's a second suzanne that you've disable in preview but not in render, impossible to say without the file as Chris says...

Comment: Possibly this is due to your environment rather than your material - if there isn’t anything to reflect then it will look plain. In material preview there is an automatic environment image of an outdoor environment with trees and sky, etc which gives it something to reflect. By default the render will be a plain environment with nothing to reflect. Either add an environment image or add other elements to your scene (eg, floor, other objects) to add some detail to the reflection.

Answer (score 1):

@Rich Sedman

You are right, it was related with the world background, I had to change it with an image and now works :)...also play around with the base color, changing for example to: Ambient Occlusion (even maybe is not the correct one, it works) So thank you everyone for your answers.[image]

[image]

[image]